How do I solve DC offset GND between 2 power supplies 220V to 12V/GND?
The setup:
Two modular synths (lets call them A and B) with each their own power supply making 220V AC into DC +12V, GND, -12V.
I measure a DC offset (like 6.5V) between the GND's of synths A+B (no modules connected).
I have a third synth (C), but that GND is OK between synth B and C.
It seems synth A has an offset originating from the power supply (measured with no modules or other boards connected). The power supply is a MeanWell RT65B.
Question: Is it possible to solve the offset in power supply A?

Is there an AC ground connection for each (or all three) devices?

Is the DC offset real or an artifact of your measurement setup (which is unknown)? What kind of power supplies these have, and what connections are between them, and how you measured there is DC offset? What if there is just AC, and the devices are floating? Usually, there would be no DC offset between devices. At least not 6.5V, even if there are few millivolts between two galvanically connected devices.

Yep, found the problem, indeed it was a lose AC ground connection. Thanks! Solved.
